# Why is TeraTerm not putting out the same bytes that are in the send call?

Tags: macros, serial-port, hyperterminal

Using `TeraTerm` and a Serial port adapter I ran a Macro with this line on it:

```
send $55 $0B $00 $00 $00 $BB $42 $AA
```

The `$BB` was sent out as two different bytes instead of just one. I forget which ones they were specifically but the result on the O-scope looked like this:

```
55 0B 00 00 00 C8 E9 42 AA
```

Does anyone know why this is?
I looked in the Manual and verified that `Send8Ctrl` is set to off and so is the Debug option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did the research, tested and verified that the answer to the question is that TeraTerm is using UTF-8 instead of English under the general settings menu. There are two options present that may be confusing so the two options are 'English' and 'Default'.